# Can Magical Lineage reduce a spell's level multiple times?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, feats, metamagic, stacking

Oh wise brains of the internet, I implore thee

[Magical Lineage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-lineage/) states "Pick one spell when you choose this trait. When you apply metamagic feats to this spell that add at least 1 level to the spell, treat its actual level as 1 lower for determining the spell’s final adjusted level."

If applying multiple metamagic feats to a spell, such as Maximized + Empowered, would Magical Lineage reduce the total adjusted level by 2 (once for each application of a metamagic feat) or only once regardless of the number of metamagic feats?

My initial take is that it only applies once, regardless of the number of metamagic feats applied, but might as well double check and make sure it's right.

I just want to know whether I should be preparing Maximized Empowered Battering Blast into a 7th level slot or a 6th level slot.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 9):

### No, only once, regardless of the number of feats.

The rules as you quoted are pretty clear:

> When you apply metamagic ***feats*** to this spell that ***add*** at least 1 level to the spell, treat its actual level as 1 lower for determining the spell’s final adjusted level."

Emphasis added. The use of plural noun and verb form cover the use of different single feats in different instances and multiple feats in one instance. In both cases, you lower the spell one level from its final adjusted level.

Comment: It also doesn't say "reduce the effective level of metamagic feats" or similar. Just the spell. It's also why it does weird things to 0 level adjustment metamagics.

Answer (score 3):

A *maximized empowered battering blast* uses a 7th level spell slot. All metamagic feats are applied to a spell simultaneously and magical lineage reduces the level of the spell by 1 a single time when you apply them - not once per feat applied.